# how to make the height of a background image (or an empty span) responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is may html markup

```
<header>
   <span> <!-- background image here -->  </span>
  <hgroup>
     <h1 class="testing">CSS3 and Compass Documentation</h1>
     <h2>here I am going to document my compass and CSS3 learning</h2>
  </hgroup>
</header>​
```

And this would be mart of my css:

```
header span {
    background: url(banner.gif) center 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    display: block;
    height: 170px;  /* maybe this is where it needs changing*/
    width: 100%; 
}
```

The problem starts once you start to making the browser window smaller (iphone size for example). The image shrinks (as I want it to) but **still the height remains `170px`** leaving a bigger gap between the image and the `hgroup` content

I have tried to use `height: 100%` but that does not work at all (in this case at least).

In case you need a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Jcp6H/

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you would like to have your `<span>` element resize with the height of your (background)image.

I would advise to use the `<img>` tag instead of a background-image.

```
<header>
    <img src="http://movethewebforward.org/css/img/beanie-webasaurs.gif" alt="Webasaurs!" />
    <hgroup>
        <h1 class="testing">CSS3 and Compass Documentation</h1>
        <h2>here I am going to document my compass and CSS3 learning</h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>​
```

​In CSS style your image that way:

```
header {
  max-width: 950px; 
}

header img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

  header h1 {
    color: #324a69;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
    position: relative; 
}

  header h2 {
    clear: both;
    color: #705635;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center; 
}​
```

It is quite hard to size the height of an element based on its background-image...

Comment: thank. But out of interest, is it posible to "size the height of an element based on its background-image..." - to get what I want

Comment: I dont think it's possible to size an element based on it background-image size. The other way around though (base a background-image size on the element size) can be achieved today quite easily with the CSS rule "background-size:cover|contain".

Answer (score 0):

First off use an image inside of your span as it makes it easier to work with.

```
 <span><img src="banner.jpg" /></span>
```

I tried this as an example you can replace with whatever you need

```
header span img {
background: #960;
display: block;
max-height: 170px;
max-width:950px;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
```

}

All you need to do is set a max-height and max-width, this way they will shrink with the browser without adding extra spaces. If needed you can also set a min-height etc to stop it going too small.

Try it and see if that works for you.